# Boot ubuntu not recognize pendrive

Tags: 14.04, boot

I have installed on my notebook ubuntu 14:04, as I am new to ubuntu, just damaging the etc folder then decided that it would re-install the system. The problem is that the boot is not starting with the stick. He always goes to a screen for me to choose between "ubuntu", "Advanced Options for ubuntu" and "setup", I click on the setup and go on the "boot" there is the following option in this order:

1. Windows Boot Manager
2. SATA CD: TSSTcorp CDDVDW SU-208GB
3. SATA HDD: ST500LM012 HN-M500MBB
4. ubuntu
5. USB FDD:
6. USB HDD:
7. NETWORK

Does not start the way to stick any, must start to re-install ubuntu 14:04.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your computer's boot order is set to look for a hard drive boot before a USB stick. Depending on the brand of your computer, hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> right after turning the computer on, should bring you into the BIOS boot menu, where you can select the USB stick to boot from.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the iso of your linux install with http://www.pendrivelinux.com/ to your usb and changing the boot order as suggested by Zac.